# How to move a child node and it's attributes to parent node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml

```
<PQIssueInquiry>
               <PQIssueslist>
              <transaction id="2013-04-29-05.03.15.644700T01">
                <id>2013-04-29-05.03.15.644700T01</id>
                <priority>999</priority>
                <issueID>20130429-152405-DT73606</issueID>
                <subject>Member</subject>
                <issueCategory>MS Care1st Member</issueCategory>
                <issueSubCategory>Demographic Change</issueSubCategory>
                <providerNumber>PCP4</providerNumber>
                <memberNumber>10020*03</memberNumber>
                <businessArea>CSMHCQA</businessArea>
                <type>ISSUE</type>
                <status>CATCHALL</status>
                <groupNumber>COMM*H</groupNumber>
                <lockStatus>ASSIGNED</lockStatus>
                <assignID>DT73606</assignID>
                <queueCode>CATCHALL</queueCode>
                <lockworkFlag>N</lockworkFlag>
                <origUserID>DT73606</origUserID>
                <CFLG>2</CFLG>
              </transaction>

            </PQIssueslist>
          </PQIssueInquiry>
```

Now, I want to remove the node  PQIssueslist from the above xml and the xml output should be like the following:

```
<PQIssueInquiry>

            <transaction id="2013-04-29-05.03.15.644700T01">
            <id>2013-04-29-05.03.15.644700T01</id>
            <priority>999</priority>
            <issueID>20130429-152405-DT73606</issueID>
            <subject>Member</subject>
            <issueCategory>MS Care1st Member</issueCategory>
            <issueSubCategory>Demographic Change</issueSubCategory>
            <providerNumber>PCP4</providerNumber>
            <memberNumber>10020*03</memberNumber>
            <businessArea>CSMHCQA</businessArea>
            <type>ISSUE</type>
            <status>CATCHALL</status>
            <groupNumber>COMM*H</groupNumber>
            <lockStatus>ASSIGNED</lockStatus>
            <assignID>DT73606</assignID>
            <queueCode>CATCHALL</queueCode>
            <lockworkFlag>N</lockworkFlag>
            <origUserID>DT73606</origUserID>
            <CFLG>2</CFLG>
          </transaction>


      </PQIssueInquiry>
```

I have done something like below to remove the specified node, But I am getting the exception as "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

The code I have used is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PQIssueslist">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Help is appreciated. I have two xsl files out of which the first one's output xml is input for the second xsl.

The first xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">

<xsl:variable name="spName" select="//PQ/PQIssueInquiry/storedProcedureName"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PQIssueslist>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="//results/row" />
         </PQIssueslist>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//results/row">
      <transaction>
              <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select=".//IKEY"/></xsl:attribute>
                <id><xsl:value-of select=".//IKEY"/></id>         
                <priority><xsl:value-of select=".//PRTY"/></priority>
                <issueID><xsl:value-of select=".//ISSUEID"/></issueID>
                <subject><xsl:value-of select=".//SUBJECT"/></subject>
                <issueCategory><xsl:value-of select=".//ISSTYP"/></issueCategory>
                <issueSubCategory><xsl:value-of select=".//ISSCAT1"/></issueSubCategory>
                <providerNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//RELPRV"/></providerNumber>
                <memberNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//RELMEM"/></memberNumber>
                <businessArea><xsl:value-of select=".//UNITCD"/></businessArea>
                <type><xsl:value-of select=".//WRKTYPE"/></type>
                <status><xsl:value-of select=".//STATCD"/></status>
                <groupNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//RELGRP"/></groupNumber>
                <lockStatus><xsl:value-of select=".//LOCKSTAT"/></lockStatus>
                <assignID><xsl:value-of select=".//ASSIGNID"/></assignID>
                <queueCode><xsl:value-of select=".//QUEUECD"/></queueCode>
                <lockworkFlag><xsl:value-of select=".//LOCKWORK_FLG"/></lockworkFlag>
                <origUserID><xsl:value-of select=".//ORIGUSERID"/></origUserID>
        <CFLG><xsl:value-of select=".//INXFLD01"/></CFLG>
        <xsl:if test="$spName = 'PQOCLKP' ">
                <callerType>Other</callerType>
                <contactName><xsl:value-of select=".//CLSTNAME"/>,&#160;<xsl:value-of select=".//CFSTNAME"/></contactName>
                <contactPhone><xsl:value-of select=".//CPHONE"/></contactPhone>
                <contactOrganization><xsl:value-of select=".//CORGNAM"/></contactOrganization>
        </xsl:if>
        </transaction>
           <xsl:if test="$spName != 'PQOCLKP' ">
               <callerType>NotOther</callerType>
           </xsl:if>
            <sort>
                <field><xsl:value-of select=".//FIELD"/></field>
                <ascending><xsl:value-of select=".//ASCENDING"/></ascending>
            </sort>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second xsl file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PQIssueslist">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sample input for the first XSL file is:

```
- <ABC>
- <PQIssueInquiry>
  <userID>DT11</userID> 
  <password>ddd</password> 
  <hostAddress>12.34.54</hostAddress> 
  <hostPort>123</hostPort> 
  <storedProcedureName>PQUSERISSLOOKUP</storedProcedureName> 
  <userName>ABC</userName> 
  <fromDate>2013-04-12-00.00.00.000000</fromDate> 
  <toDate>2013-05-11-23.59.59.999999</toDate> 
  </PQIssueInquiry>
- <AWDSRVRunStoredProcedure xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
  <hostAddress>10.193.236.57</hostAddress> 
  <hostPort>12955</hostPort> 
  <timeout>120000</timeout> 
  <trace>0</trace> 
  <readable>N</readable> 
  <userID>DT77214</userID> 
- <storedProcedure id="DUMMY">
- <row>
  <ISSTYP>MS Care1st Member</ISSTYP> 
  <ISSCAT1>Demographic Change</ISSCAT1> 
  <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD> 
  <ORIGUSERID>DT73606</ORIGUSERID> 
  <PRTY>999</PRTY> 
  <WRKTYPE>ISSUE</WRKTYPE> 
  <ASSIGNID>DT73606</ASSIGNID> 
  <RELGRP>COMM*H</RELGRP> 
  <INXFLD01>2</INXFLD01> 
  <SUBJECT>Member</SUBJECT> 
  <QUEUECD>CATCHALL</QUEUECD> 
  <ISSUEID>20130429-152405-DT73606</ISSUEID> 
  <STATCD>CATCHALL</STATCD> 
  <IKEY>2013-04-29-05.03.15.644700T01</IKEY> 
  <RELPRV>PCP4</RELPRV> 
  <RELMEM>10020*03</RELMEM> 
  <LOCKWORK_FLG>N</LOCKWORK_FLG> 
  <LOCKSTAT>ASSIGNED</LOCKSTAT> 
  </row>
-
  </list>
  </ABC>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `</PQIssueInquiry>` at the end of the input sample, that is the problem, independent of any XSLT. The XSLT is fine, but you need to feed a well-formed XML input sample.

Comment: There was a copy paste problem earlier. Now, I have corrected. The root node is PQIssueInquiry. I want to move all the elements and their values under PQIssueslist to directly under PQIssueInquiry node and remove the PQIssueslist  node.

Comment: @user3177203, I don't see any correction in your input sample. And if you continue to get errors by the XML parser then you need to make sure both your XML input as well as the XSLT are well-formed. I assume you have a complete stylesheet although you haven't posted that either so it is not possible to tell you where the error comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I could not able to edit the description of the question due to an error thrown by stackoverflow.

Comment: How to add the code to the thread once the question is asked..cozz I am unable to add the code since it has more characters.

Comment: There is an edit link below your question that you can use to edit the question, including the code samples.

Comment: I have added the xsl files now. Could you please take a look now?

Comment: What is the current state of the problem, do you still get the error "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed" or is that resolved?

Comment: That was a copy paste issue. Now, I have corrected by editing the description one more time. Sorry for the confusion. Still not able to move the desired node and getting the same error as  "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed"

Comment: I can run your second stylesheet against the edited input sample just fine. What is the input for the first stylesheet?

Comment: Added the sample input xml for first xsl file.

Comment: The latest sample is not well-formed: unexpected characters in element end tag (expected "storedProcedure")

Comment: It is just a sample. Still not sure why the code in the second xsl file is not able to move the specified node.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no problem with the first xsl.I am getting the error with second xsl file. especially with the code" <xsl:template match="PQIssueslist">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:template> "

Comment: When I run by omitting the second xsl file, there is no exception. But, when I include it, the exception is thrown. I need the second xsl to move the specified node. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You will need to provide samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.